# Friction as differential 1-form

Tags: physics, differential-forms

Is there a way to write the work done by friction as a differential form? Intuitively I'll write it as
$$w = uN \, |dx|$$

but I suppose this is not properly a 1-form (cause of $|dx|$). Am I right?

It's possible?

Thanks

Comment: In a general setting, you're right. In a specific case it might however be possible.

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: When you make differential forms orientation-independent (as you're doing with your absolute value), you're talking about things called *densities* as opposed to forms. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold).

Comment: Do you have other references?